# using 2 different jquery t-datepickers in the same page

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I am trying to use 2 different t-datepikers in the same page.

html code is

```
  <div class="t-datepicker">
  <div class="t-check-in"></div>
  <div class="t-check-out"></div>
</div>
    <div class="class_a">
      <div class="t-check-in"></div>
  <div class="t-check-out"></div>
    </div>
```

and script to call the t-datepicker is

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.t-datepicker').tDatePicker({
      // Global options
    autoClose: true,
      limitNextMonth: 3,
      numCalendar : 1,
      dateRangesHover: false
    });
    $('.class_a').tDatePicker({
      // Options for .class_a
              limitNextMonth: 4,
      numCalendar : 2,
      dateRangesHover: true
    });

  });
</script>
```

the first datepicker appears and the html has class t-datepicker-open

on clicking the second picker at class_a

the class t-datepicker-open appears but then instantly disappears so second datepicker is not working.

According to documentation it should work as instructions for multiple pickers are:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.t-datepicker').tDatePicker({
      // Global options
    });
    $('.class_a').tDatePicker({
      // Options for .class_a
    });
    $('.class_b').tDatePicker({
      // Options for .class_b
    });
  });
</script>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

[Live demo](https://repl.it/repls/NuttyExcitableBlogware)

**html**

```
<div class="t-datepicker class_a">
  <div class="t-check-in"></div>
  <div class="t-check-out"></div>
</div>

<div class="t-datepicker class_b">
  <div class="t-check-in"></div>
  <div class="t-check-out"></div>
</div>
```

**js**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.class_a').tDatePicker({
        // options only here
        autoClose: true,
        limitNextMonth: 3,
        numCalendar : 1,
        dateRangesHover: false
    });
    $('.class_b').tDatePicker({
        // options only here
        limitNextMonth: 4,
        numCalendar : 2,
        dateRangesHover: true
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: @A.V. Try this now

Comment: do you know how to disbled all future dates, after selecting a date for check in but after the first disabled date on the calendar? I have created an array with disabled dates dateDisabled:["2020-05-24","2020-05-25","2020-05-26","2020-05-27","2020-05-28","2020-05-29"]. So when I click chek in 10/05/2020 to disable and not allow to click all dates after 24/05/2020.

Comment: Try setting *'setEndDate'*. [Reference](https://t-datepicker.getqwerty.com/methods.html)

Comment: well what I am trying to do is dynamic as an array with disabled dates might be ["2020-05-24","2020-05-25","2020-05-26","2020-05-27","2020-05-28","2020-05-29", "2020-07-12", "2020-07-13","2020-07-14","2020-07-15","2020-07-16"] so when click check in 10/05/2020 disable all future dates after 24/05/2020 and if clicked check in 01/07/2020 disable all future dates after 12/07/2020. In both cases disabled dates are all future when check in date is clicked , after first disabled after check in.